# no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'Briques' and 'int' )

Tags: c++, debugging, codeblocks

I've got an error on this line:

```
Briques brique = brique[i][j];
```

saying:

> no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'Briques' and 'int' ) ...

I don't understand why, since `Briques` is a class defined in `Table.h`:

```
class Briques {
public:
    int type;
    bool state;
};
```

And `Table.h` got:

```
Briques brique[BOARD_WIDTH][BOARD_HEIGHT];
```

Any help would be appreciated. I think the error means the class `Briques` doesn't take into consideration arrays? Or something like that... But I can't solve the problem.

Also if you need more code about something do tell me, new here! :D

Comment: It's about the name. If you declare a new variable `brique`, it hides the previous use of that name.

Comment: @BoPersson ohhh got it, thanks! That was such a newbie mistake it's funny XD

Answer (score 3):

Your code `Briques brique = brique[i][j];` is not what you intended.

You want to declare a variable `brique` initialized from another variable `brique` in an outer scope, but the compiler is first looking for the closest variable in scope for initialization.

Because you have a variable named `brique` in the local scope (the one you're declaring), it is used for initialization, but this local `brique` you're declaring is of type `Briques` (unlike the one you wanted which is of type `Brique[][]`), and indeed it doesn't have `operator[]` declared.

Just change your declaration:

```
Briques b = brique[i][j];
```

Avoid name conflicts in your code.

Comment: Thanks... that seemed to work!

Comment: It's not "ambiguous". If it were ambiguous then it would not be able to compile. The standard describes precisely what the program's semantics are (and those are as you describe in your second paragraph). It just doesn't mean what the OP intended.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you're right, "ambiguous" was a malapropism here. I edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `brique` as your new variable name.

If you do this, `brique[x][y]` will refer to your newly-defined `brique` and will cause the error.

Answer (score 1):

```
Briques brique[BOARD_WIDTH][BOARD_HEIGHT];
Briques brique = brique[i][j];
```

Whith this two line you have two declaration for the same name `brique`

In the second line  `brique[i][j];`

refers to the last object named `brique` you have declare :

```
Briques brique = brique[i][j];
```

So you're doing something like :

```
Object a = a[i][j];
```